# CSS: Remove Line Height (leading) on larger text

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the leading from the mandatory span so that the `<<` has no additional space above and below.

The field row occupies a certain height based on the default `line-height` for the text size, the mandatory field however is taller because the font size is larger. How can I strip out the extra white space above and below the `<<`?

```css
.fieldRow { /* for illustration only */
        border: solid 1px #f00;  
}
.mandatory {
        color: #f00;
 border: solid 1px #f00; /* for illustration only */
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldRow">
  
 <label for="select">Some field</label>
 
 <select name="select">
  <option>Any</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
 </select> 
 
 <span class="mandatory">&laquo;</span>

</div>
```

Comment: You can't, that white space is part of the character. Best bet is `display: inline-block; margin-top: -6px;` then remove the border

Comment: The mandatory span has a different `font-size` to its container, if you ensure they both have the same font size then the white space is a lot less

Comment: also remember, due to the borders the white space will look 2px bigger than they actually are

Comment: A more robust way is to try and find a character (perhaps an arrow character) that you can use in normal size, or to use an image. Using quotation marks as sort-of arrows leads to problems like this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After removing `vertical-align: middle` it looks good to me.

```
.mandatory {
  color: #f00;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/IdeAq)

Answer (score 3):

Remove vertical-align

```
.mandatory {
    color: #f00;
    border: solid 1px #f00; /* for illustration only */
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 0 !important;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj9qX/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I had a similar problem and came up with a different solution.

It's a bit hacky, but you can put a container around the text, then use overflow hidden and give it a height. The extra space under the larger font will be cut off by the containing div. You're not getting rid of it, but your hiding it. This works for me, may not work in your situation though.

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px; /* Or whatever height is necessary to show the text */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="mandatory">&laquo;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've added various bits of styling which have added the whitespace in, namely the `font-size` of the mandatory span is different to it's container.

The border you've added also makes things look a bit worse than they are.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k3tz/), it looks a lot better when you remove the above.

Revised CSS:

```css
.fieldRow {
  border: solid 1px #f00;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.mandatory {
  color: #f00;
  border: solid 1px #f00;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
line-height: unset;
```

or
line-height: unset !important;