# CSS: Understanding and adjusting leading / line-height of fonts

Tags: font-face, font-size, css

A very similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701110/css-remove-line-height-leading-on-larger-text) but the really answered sufficiently...

The CSS line-height property controls the amount of white space above the letters. Making it bigger/smaller spaces rows of text farther/closer together. But if you set the line height to the exact same value as the font-size, the text will still have white space above them.

So this DOESN'T quite work...

```
div { height: 80px; }
span { font-size : 80px; line-height : 80px; }
<div>
<span>Foo</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s_d_p/yMHVs/

The degree to which the enclosed text actually matches the container height seems to differ from font to font.

So my question is two parts:

1. What are we actually adjusting when we set line-height?
2. Is there a way to remove it entirely so that letter fit precisely inside their container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the remaining/extra space is typically a symptom of the font being used, as designated by its designer.

[image]

Thus, the 80px includes the allocated white space above and/or below. Additional white space above is typically provided to allow for accented characters, which would otherwise require the letter itself to be compressed- producing an inconsistent typeface.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119878/how-to-remove-space-at-top-of-p-tag-align-contained-text-to-top-of-container) & [here for further information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244305/why-browsers-reserve-space-for-accented-characters-even-if-there-is-not-one).

Line height refers to the total height of the typeface, inclusive of any allocated whitespace.

Comment: Thanks. One follow-up. How does the arbitrary amount of whitespace set by the designer interact with the font-size property? Does font-size :16px mean the entire character + whitespace will be 16px tall? So the actual glyph will always be that height less the whitespace?

Comment: Yes, the font-size is always inclusive of any allocated whitespace

Answer (score 2):

i'm sure that space is reserved for some characters that need more space. like this one:

[image]

`Fj╛`

character "j" need more space that "F" and i'm sure again that there is other characters (like "╛") that needs some space in above and bottom. so font designer reserved this space for that characters.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yMHVs/3/)