# Create great capital letter like in old books

Tags: css, layout, fonts

My question is how to achieve something like this:

```
 _
| |     orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
| |__   sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
|____|  aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Where the Capital letter should be a single letter, not an image.

Edit: The answer of @umesh-sinha resulted in the following:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do like  this:

```
p:first-letter{
    font-size:300%;
    float:left;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

[image]

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/4DYRJ/1/) - 
[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/4DYRJ/3/)

Comment: Works, but looks ugly with used capital letter font "Baroque Script" http://www.1001freefonts.com/baroque_script.font There's a ca. 2em high bottom padding below the capital letter (font dependent). Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: can your create a fiddle ? @the_Seppi

Comment: @the_Seppi this is about the font, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269168/css-understanding-and-adjusting-leading-line-height-of-fonts/20269445#20269445

Comment: thanks... so there's no way to "fix" this? EDIT: Got it: http://jsfiddle.net/MW7xW/2/

Comment: you can use higher `font-size` that `line-height`, here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MW7xW/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CSS.
Try following-

```
p:first-letter
{
font-size:200%;
color:#000000;
}
```

and you may do this too,

CSS

```
.first
{
    float:left;
    font-size:500%;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:5px;
    color:#8C8273;
}
```

HTML

```
<p><span class="first">T</span>ext here</p>
```